# How to set timeout for Azure IoT Hub messages via MQTT?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I am currently trying to send messages to the Azure IoT Hub using MQTT and the C library. When sending a message via IoTHubDeviceClient_SendEventAsync shortly after the network connection is lost, it takes several minutes until the callback is called.

Is there any way to shorten this time to get faster response if the connection is lost?

Answer (score 0):

You can set "timeout" and "messageTimeout" with [IoTHubClient_SetOption()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-c-sdk-ref/iothub-client-h/iothubclient-setoption).
Maybe setting the retry policy with [IoTHubClient_SetRetryPolicy()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-c-sdk-ref/iothub-client-h/iothubclient-setretrypolicy) is also helpful for you.

Comment: According to https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/master/iothub_client/inc/iothub_client_options.h messageTimeout is deprecated